# gcc Compiler configuration: no C++!

Tags: codeblocks

Can I set the gcc-compiler to only compile C-code? My main concern is, that I **want** to get a compiler error, if I try to use any C++ syntax, or even try to make use of the STL. Since I'm using Codeblocks it would be nice if you could point out how to change it there, but I'm sure I'd figure that bit out.

Comment: Just had to realize that choosing "C" as the project language does the trick. However that would still leave the question if you can change this "manually", say you have accidentally chosen C++ for your project and now you want to change it to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -std option, for example gcc -std=c89 says you want it to behave as if you are compiling C89 code. You will also probably want to use the -pedantic option, and give your files the .c extension, rather than .cpp. Also, gcc likes to allow its own extensions, which are not part of C or C++, and -pedantic will turn most of these off.

Comment: Why `-pedantic` ? He's trying to stay away from C++, not to follow the letter of the standard.

Comment: @cnicular See my edit. And following the letter of the the standard is A Good Thing to do.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I think I see your point. Still, I *like* certain features of c99.

Comment: @cnicular Fine! In that case use -std=c99. I was giving *an example* not saying that was what he must use!

Comment: Alternatively you could put `-x c` into the compiler options. That tells gcc that whatever you compile is a C file (without explicitly specifying a standard), even if it has a .cpp extension or no extension at all.